# OpenCV Python Performance

Tags: python, performance, opencv

I am a Python and OpenCV newbie. I was dealing with OpenCV optimization and I found [Measuring Performance with OpenCV](http://docs.opencv.org/master/dc/d71/tutorial_py_optimization.html#gsc.tab=0) website. I saw `cv2.getTickCount` and `cv2.getTickFrequency` and tried on a blank Video Capture code:

```
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
time1 = 0

while True:
    e1 = cv2.getTickCount()
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    cv2.imshow("cam", frame)
    e2 = cv2.getTickCount()
    time1 = (e2 - e1) / cv2.getTickFrequency() + time1
    print time1

    k = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF

    if k == ord('q'):
        break
```

At the same time, I tried `time.time()` for performance measuring:

```
import cv2
import time

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

t_start = time.time()
time1 = 0

while True:
    e1 = cv2.getTickCount()
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    cv2.imshow("cam", frame)
    e2 = cv2.getTickCount()
    time1 = (e2 - e1) / cv2.getTickFrequency() + time1
    elapsedTime = time.time()-t_start
    print [time1, elapsedTime]

    k = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF

    if k == ord('q'):
        break
```

There is a huge difference between `elapsedTime` and `time1`, like:

```
[23.544186313842033, 29.413000106811523]
[23.588920849343307, 29.460999965667725]
[23.636793986833897, 29.51200008392334]
[23.669538024648435, 29.558000087738037]
[23.701628712445952, 29.605000019073486]
[23.737225731551163, 29.65499997138977]
[23.775527056696312, 29.703999996185303]
[23.82555789141547, 29.765000104904175]
[23.864218735017026, 29.813999891281128]
[23.901782255564854, 29.861000061035156]
```

I checked both outputs and my phone's chronometer is with `time.time()`'s side.

My questions are:

1. Why I have this difference? How and why `cv2.getTickCount` and
   `cv2.getTickFrequency` differs from `time.time()`
2. To do the performance measurement, which one should I use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not really proficient with `cv2` but I do see something *rather iffy* with your timing technique here.

Look at what part of the code you are measuring with `cv2.getTickCount()`:

```
e1 = cv2.getTickCount()  # start
ret, frame = cap.read()
cv2.imshow("cam",frame)
e2 = cv2.getTickCount()  # stop
```

Now, look at what you are measuring using `time.time()`:

```
t_start=time.time()  # start
time1=0

while True:
    e1 = cv2.getTickCount()
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    cv2.imshow("cam",frame)
    e2 = cv2.getTickCount()
    time1 = (e2 - e1)/ cv2.getTickFrequency() + time1
    elapsedTime= time.time()-t_start  # stop
```

You are obviously mistreating poor ol' `time` over here by counting different things. Unfortunately, I cannot verify the actual runtimes because I do not have OpenCV, but, you might want to put your `time` calls on par with `getTickCount()`. In short, use something similar to this:

```
time1=0

while True:
    t_start = time.time()  # start
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    cv2.imshow("cam",frame)
    elapsedTime= time.time()-t_start  # stop
```

And re-evaluate your results, it's quite possible `getTickCount()` will get more accurate results than `time` because of the way it is implemented, I really can't know that.

---

As for *which one should you use?* `cv2`'s internal timing module.

*Why?* Because, without making outlandish claims, it is *a tested module* that has *probably* been developed by people that are most likely more proficient than us with `Python`. Timing on your own can be *a tricky thing* and leaves a lot of room for little mistakes, especially when you're first starting out.

So, in short, go with `getTickCount()`, it is there for a reason.

Comment: I changed the code as you suggested and I got better results: they are nearly same.

[41.4705076101 41.2309985161]

I also changed the code and used 1000 samples for `time.time()` and `time1`. If I print the result for every loop, difference gets bigger between these two piece of codes. In the mean time, If I print the final result at the end, I have more meaningful results

Answer (score 0):

This should produce consistent results:

```
t_start = time.time()
e1 = cv2.getTickCount()

while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    cv2.imshow("cam",frame)
    e2 = cv2.getTickCount()
    current_time = time.time() 
    time1 = (e2 - e1)/ cv2.getTickFrequency()
    elapsedTime= current_time - t_start
    print [time1 , elapsedTime]
```

Actually, I cannot reproduce your problem:

```
import time
import cv2

t_start = time.time()
e1 = cv2.getTickCount()

for x in range(10):
    time.sleep(0.1)
    e2 = cv2.getTickCount()
    time1 = (e2 - e1)/ cv2.getTickFrequency()
    elapsedTime= time.time() - t_start
    print 'new:', [time1 , elapsedTime]

t_start=time.time()
time1=0

for x in range(10):

    e1 = cv2.getTickCount()
    time.sleep(0.1)
    e2 = cv2.getTickCount()
    time1 = (e2 - e1)/ cv2.getTickFrequency() + time1
    elapsedTime= time.time()-t_start
    print 'old:', [time1 , elapsedTime]
```

Pints rather consistent values:

```
new: [0.101121973, 0.10170483589172363]
new: [0.202431593, 0.20299196243286133]
new: [0.303379863, 0.3039419651031494]
new: [0.404390379, 0.40494799613952637]
new: [0.505434471, 0.5059988498687744]
new: [0.606657266, 0.6072208881378174]
new: [0.70785313, 0.7083899974822998]
new: [0.808160676, 0.808696985244751]
new: [0.90930442, 0.9098358154296875]
new: [1.010264773, 1.0107979774475098]
old: [0.101093147, 0.10112500190734863]
old: [0.201946665, 0.20209193229675293]
old: [0.302889158, 0.3032569885253906]
old: [0.40368225999999996, 0.40418291091918945]
old: [0.504733644, 0.5053050518035889]
old: [0.605701044, 0.6063768863677979]
old: [0.7066711290000001, 0.707442045211792]
old: [0.807242644, 0.8081610202789307]
old: [0.908066402, 0.9092309474945068]
old: [1.008913762, 1.0102128982543945]
```

Are you sure the printed numbers correspond to code you show in your question?